# have an MP3\WAV in backgroung of HTML

Tags: html, audio, background, mp3

i want to have an MP3 constantly playing and looping in an HTML page after a page has been loaded. I also want to control this sound with HTML interface for PLAY\STOP and if i can tune up down the  volume as well then it would be great but that's an optional. Is there a way to first load the sound file first and play it in a loop or every sound has to be streamed.

All you people with due respect, please! please! stick to HTML and Javascript, please make no suggestions like have a Flash in your page or have a hidden Flash in your page or have Windows API calls to adjust volumes.

How can i make this method light enough to also work well for 56K Dial-up Modems.

Comment: Please don't have music constantly playing and looping in the background.  It gives me nightmares of the 90s and the <blink> tag.

But the answer is perhaps the new <audio> tag in html5.  It will only work in newer browsers (except IE) though.

Comment: I almost want to retag this as "painful"

Comment: <p>If you would like to listen to music while browsing my pages, feel free to chose any title from your collection</p> =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in html you cannot playback MP3 files - you're looking for some javascript that does this job. 
script.aculo.us frameworks has some built-in features for this or otherwise I'd suggest you this tutorial, which covers the basics...

[O'Reilly Media](http://digitalmedia.oreilly.com/2005/02/23/mp3_embed.html)

Answer (score 3):

Short of HTML5, you can't do this with just HTML and Javascript.

Even [Google uses Flash](http://lifehacker.com/391810/google-inline-mp3-player-user-script-streams-linked-mp3s) for their embedded audio player.

Answer (score 1):

So, just HTML and JavaScript and no third party stuff…

Use the poorly supported (and draft) [audio element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#audio) and watch as people who have supporting browsers flee from the noise. Making it light enough for 56k modem users is more a question of making the sound file tiny than anything else — but those users probably won't have upgraded to browsers that support the audio element anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.conradaskland.com/blog/2006/11/html-code-to-auto-play-mp3-audio-files/), [this](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/html/107794/107794/play--mp3-file-in-background-/) may get you started. However, youre dreaming if you want users with 56k to be able to play any MP3's at a decent quality (except for maybe talk shows on the radio).

Comment: Those options lack the required ability to start/pause the playback.